# Can't add service account to new Google Analytics UI

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

With the old Google Analytics UI I could easily add service account email addresses, but with the new UI, I am unable to.

Every time I try to add the service account email, it says the email cannot be found.

My service account email looks like: projectName@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

[image: New UI]

Comment: Have to enabled the analytics API from the developer console?

Comment: Yes, I also get:  <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?alt=json returned "User does not have any Google Analytics account."> - but I do!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I needed to create a new service account user, which had the format like:

CUSTOM_NAME@PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com